# How to start VMX86 (VMWare Player) in the safe mode

Tags: windows, safe-mode, vmware-player

I have a limited RAM, and I want to run 4 ubuntu virtual machines using VMWare player. So, I have started my windows 7 in safe mode to save RAM and am trying to start VMWare Player in safe mode. But when I start the VMs, this error pops up:

```
Unable to open kernel device "\\.\Global\vmx86": The system cannot find the file specified. Did you reboot after installing VMware Player?

Failed to initialize monitor device.
```

I read somewhere that a driver has to be started for that, which is vmx86, But when I try to start is using

```
net start vmx86
```

The following error pops up,

```
System error 1084 has occurred.

This service cannot be started in Safe Mode
```

Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the `programming` question?

Comment: I thought stackoverflow could be used for such technical problems also. :-/

Comment: Why don't you add more RAM?